# Roll down for floating rate notes

Tags: bond, risk-management, floating-rate

is it correct to say that floating rate notes (FRNs) have no roll-down for a time horizon as it is interest risk free?

Comment: what is your definition of roll-down? What does your question mean?

Comment: it is the typical roll down definition. I guess FRN does have carry roll down, but it is very small as it is like a fixed rate bond with very short maturity/duration?

Comment: @Attack68 my definition of roll down is the price change of the bond due to the fact that it gets shorter and therefore has a lower yield given an upward sloping yield curve. is there any other definition?

Answer (score 0):

This is correct for pure floaters; that is, bond that have no margin. If there is margin, it likely rolls down as the bond approaches maturity

Comment: Also, if the coupons are set in advance, rather than in arreas, then after the upcoming coupon is fixed, it too is subject to rolldown during the coupon period,.